# Free Software to create ISO from Folders

Tags: windows-7, iso

I'm looking for a software that would create ISO files from folder/s in Windows 7.

If possible, something fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/)

- Free
- Can create an ISO image from files and folders, which you add to your compilation by drag & drop

See the [manual for how to save a compilation as an ISO file](https://cdburnerxp.se/help/Data/createiso).

*Warning:* Be sure to download the Candy-free version of it in order to avoid adware!
Click on *“more dowload options”* on the [official download page](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with most file archive applications including one called [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/). All you need to do is,

1. Open WinRAR
2. Naviagate and select the files and/or folders you want in the archive
3. Click "Add"
4. A window will popup, simply rename the file extension to ".iso" and make sure the archive format is set to "RAR"

[image: 1]

Comment: When I did that I couldn't open that ISO with Daemon tools, got an error "Unrecognized media or invalid format." Although I didn't tried to burn that ISO...